# environment variables not detected in .bashrc and .profile

Tags: bashrc

I tried to create an environment variable in my `~/.bashrc` file as follows:

`export DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT=true`

After doing some troubleshooting it appears bash isn't picking up the new environment variable at all. I tried setting it in `~/profile` but that hasn't worked either. (I edited both files under `sudo`) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `man bash` and take a look at the *INVOCATION* part. This describes in details what files are used when.

Comment: Why did you use `sudo` to edit these files? They belong to your user, not to root.

Comment: Maybe you hadn't reloaded your shell?

Comment: To narrow the problem: Is the variable set after sourcing `. ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Your title (correctly) references `~/.profile` but your question body says `~/profile`. In which one did you actually put the environment variable?

Answer (score 3):

Editing the file is not enough. You need to source that file. This is done usually when you start bash, but if you edited the file, you can force to read the file with:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Note: some systems could restrict what file is parsed at start of bash (e.g. if the file is writable by "other", or just different requiring different files, but AFAIK it is not often done, but on special devices)

EDIT:

You wrote that you edited the file with sudo. this could be a problem: if your user cannot read that file, the file is ignored. `.bashrc` is read as your user.  But also this should not be a normal case: the files should already exists, and only bad editors will change permission of edited file.

Answer (score -3):

Answer: I forgot to put `true` in quotes.

Comment: No, that was not the issue. It ought to have worked without the quotes too.